# Compress Alamofire upload request

Tags: ios, swift, compression, gzip, alamofire

My app is currently sending a large amount of file (I'd say ~14Mo) to my server but this ends up taking a longer time than I'd like.

I know Alamofire handles compression on download requests but Would like some help trying to achieve this while uploading.

```swift
self.manager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    let photo1Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.client.gif!.frameImages![0])
    let photo2Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.client.gif!.frameImages![1])
    let photo3Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.client.gif!.frameImages![2])
    let photo4Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.client.gif!.frameImages![3])
    let photo5Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.client.gif!.frameImages![4])
    multipartFormData.append(photo1Data!, withName: "photo1", fileName: "photo1.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    multipartFormData.append(photo2Data!, withName: "photo2", fileName: "photo2.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    multipartFormData.append(photo3Data!, withName: "photo3", fileName: "photo3.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    multipartFormData.append(photo4Data!, withName: "photo4", fileName: "photo4.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    multipartFormData.append(photo5Data!, withName: "photo5", fileName: "photo5.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    multipartFormData.append(URL(fileURLWithPath: self.client.videoPath!), withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
    if (self.client.firstname != nil) {
        multipartFormData.append(self.client.firstname!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "firstname")
    }
    if (self.client.lastname != nil) {
        multipartFormData.append(self.client.lastname!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "lastname")
    }
    if (self.client.age != nil) {
        multipartFormData.append(self.client.age!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "age")
    }
    if (self.client.email != nil) {
        multipartFormData.append(self.client.email!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "email")
    }
    if (self.client.male){
        multipartFormData.append("true".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "male")
    } else {
        multipartFormData.append("false".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "male")
    }
    if (self.client.newsletter){
        multipartFormData.append("true".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "newsletter")
    } else {
        multipartFormData.append("false".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "newsletter")
    }
}, to: url, method: .post, headers: nil, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        let _ = upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            if (response.response?.statusCode == 200) {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: self.client.videoPath!))
                } catch {
                    print("DID NOT DELETE VIDEO FILE")
                }
                self.client.delete()
            }
        })
        break
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print("error:\(encodingError)")
        break
    }
})
```

where client and gif are NSManagedObject inherited and related to each other. the gif frames are stored in the gif.frameImages attribute, the filePath to the generated videoFile are in the client.videoPath attribute.

is there any way to compress the multipartFormData in this case ?

I do not wish to use UIImageJPEGRepresentation either because I want the files to be true pngs on the server.

Comment: Maybe this link could be useful to understand it.

[Multi-part Request with Gzip compression](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1398)

They explain that compression into upload request is not supported, but you can do by yourself.

However, I have found this article that speak about that: [Gzipped request body in Alamofire](http://allocinit.io/ios/gzip-alamofire/), I guess it could be helpful to you.

Comment: @AlejandroVisiedo I already ran into that GitHub issue and the article, as for the issue since I'm looking for help on this matter unfortunately it didn't help me much except in knowing that it wouldn't be as simple as for downloading with alamofire. The article uses request instead of upload and I only have experience uploading a multipartFormData with the `upload` method if you know how to do the equivalent to my method using the `request` method could you post an answer with it and the link in case it would be my solution ?